# My F3 Key Won't Show My XYZ Coordinates and Everything I Try Doesn't Work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I did *EVERYTHING* Including setting the gamerule reducedBugInfo to false and it *STILL* doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score -2):

If you are on a mac, you have to hold fn+f3.